# Могу ли я каким либо образом отправить вебсокет запрос в уже открытый вебсокет?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Мне нужно отправить какое-либо сообщение в уже открытый вебсокет запрос, не открывая новый, но вопрос в том как это сделать.?
Есть сайт, который при определенном случае открывает вебсокет, чтобы не терять это соединение, тратя время на его закрытие, открытие через код, чтобы отправить сообщение, нужно отправить сообщение в этот уже открытый вебсокет, не открывая новый.

```
const socket = ??? // мне нужно каким-то образом получить уже открытый вебсокет, который был открыт сайтом
socket.send("123123")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если есть открытый значит есть и место (переменная) где он хранится. Зачастую это объект window, ищите там сокет

Comment: Покажите как вы создаете сокет

Comment: Можно попробовать через `Proxy` при создании сокета словить его (сокет).

Answer (score 0):

```
WebSocket.prototype.send = function(...args) {
    if (window.sockets.indexOf(this) === -1)
      window.sockets.push(this);
    return originalSend.call(this, ...args);
  };
sockets[sockets.length-1].send("123")
// Вылавливает открытый запрос, сохраняет в переменную, после отправляется сообщение на последний открытый запрос(в моем случае самый последний запрос - нужный)
```